# GraphHopper .jar only log Errors, Bad Requests, etc

Tags: java, logging, routes, navigation, graphhopper

I'm using GrpahHopper's self hosted routing server [v0.5](https://graphhopper.com/public/releases/graphhopper-web-0.5.0-bin.zip), running on Ubuntu 15.10.

The solution is run via a terminal with a jar file and arbitrary OSM data.

Is there a way to control the logged output of the server (e.g. to only show exceptions, bad requests, etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you'll have to repackage GraphHopper as there is no 'outside' configuration option provided - raise an issue if you need this.

Change the log4j.xml file under `web/src/main/resources` e.g. replace the root and com.graphhopper logger via the following snippet:

```
<logger name="com.graphhopper" additivity="false">
    <level value="warn" />
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNC" />
</logger>
<root>
    <priority value="warn"></priority>
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNC"/>
</root>
```

Then repackage GH via the [quickstart from source](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/master/docs/core/quickstart-from-source.md).

**Update** it might be possible without repackaging via

`export JAVA_OPTS="-Dlog4j.debug -Dlog4j.configuration=some-log-config.xml"`

using the mentioned and updated log4j.xml but I've not tested this yet. See the [log4j docs](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html)